# ORA-00902 for function that returns a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to get a list of months starting from a desired date until the current month, then I made this package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DATE_EXTENSIONS IS
   TYPE MONTH_RECORD IS RECORD (
      MONTH_YEAR DATE,
      MONTH_INDEX NUMBER
    );
   TYPE MONTH_TABLE IS TABLE OF MONTH_RECORD;
   FUNCTION GET_DATE RETURN DATE;
   FUNCTION GET_MONTHS(D IN DATE) RETURN MONTH_TABLE;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DATE_EXTENSIONS IS

   FUNCTION GET_DATE RETURN DATE IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN(SYSDATE);
   END GET_DATE;

   FUNCTION GET_MONTHS(D IN DATE) RETURN MONTH_TABLE IS
      T MONTH_TABLE;
   BEGIN
      SELECT ADD_MONTHS(D, ROWNUM - 1) AS MONTH_YEAR,
             ROWNUM AS MONTH_INDEX BULK COLLECT
        INTO T
        FROM DUAL
       WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(GET_DATE(), D) >= 0
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(GET_DATE(), D));
      RETURN T;
   END;
END;
```

The query works fine, as you can see here:

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE - 300, ROWNUM - 1) AS MONTH_YEAR, ROWNUM AS R
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 300) >= 0
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, SYSDATE - 300))
```

But when I try to encapsulate inside the package, I get the ORA-00902 error. BTW, the `GET_DATE()` function is for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you really getting an error compiling the package?  It compiles just fine for me.  Or are you getting an error when you try to call the procedure?  That works fine for me but I may be calling it differently than you are.  If you are getting an error when calling the procedure, can you post the code that you are using?  My wild guess is that the caller isn't declaring the variable to fetch your collection into correctly.

Comment: Is your caller declaring its own record and table type, instead of using the types from your package? Or trying to use the returned table type in plain SQL, perhaps? Adding the whole error stack to your question would be helpful too.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error when I call it. Humm... I am trying to use as a simple SELECT... like this: 

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DATE_EXTENSIONS.GET_MONTHS(SYSDATE - 300));

Comment: If you want to call the procedure like that, you really want to define the type in SQL rather than PL/SQL (so create an object type in SQL rather than a record type in PL/SQL and declare a collection of the object type in SQL rather than a collection in PL/SQL).  Generally, you'd want to make it a pipelined table function though that's less important as here when the number of rows returned is small.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. I created an object and the corresponding table outside the package.